# How can I do conversions from OD&D to nWoD?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, osr, conversion, changeling-the-lost

I'm running a *Changeling: the Lost* game and I'm going to be running an OD&D (clone) module soon ([Death•Frost•Doom](http://www.lotfp.com/RPG/products/death-frost-doom)) and I was wondering if anyone had tips on converting the crunchy bits to nWoD.  For example:

> Hideous Undead Thing: AC as leather, 2 HD, 12hp, Move as unencumbered
>   man, One bite and two claw attacks doing d6/d4/d4 damage, anyone hit
>   must make a paralyzation save of be unable to move for d12 turns. Has
>   regular undead immunities.

I'm not 100% sure how all those things would work in nWoD.  In addition to that there are lots of various saves and spells that I'm not sure about.  If there are resources on how to do this I'd really appreciate it.  If not, I can always wing it :-)

Comment: As you suspect, this would be a case-by-case basis kind of thing. OD&D was largely a wing-it kind of system, and the aims of both systems are different enough that you'd be essentially starting from scratch each time.

Comment: One of your biggest challenges is going to be the "Attack roll Successes = Damage". As for the saves, You can convert that into a Stamina roll at a set difficulty... AC = Armor (which just reduces the attacker's dice pool, so tweak that carefully)

Comment: In my experience the various WoD favours tend to play very well to the strengths of their themes, but from a brief glance I don't see anything about that module that really makes Changeling stand out as an obvious choice. Was there anything in particular that made you think the two would be a good match or was it more a case of having two things you wanted to play and shoving then together to see what happens?

Comment: @Braiba: actually the oath that must be sworn near the end of the adventure works better for CtL than OD&D.  Aside from that, it sounded like a fun adventure to scare the characters with.  It works out fairly well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there are any pre-made materials for this kind of conversion, so I'll give you some guidelines.

**Combat Conversions**

The biggest problem you'll run into is Attack and Damage are resolved in a single roll. You'll need to do your best to balance the dice pool your example zombie is going to have in comparison to its damage. I would also say that [J Grim's suggestion](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/11212/1736) about looking for pre-made zombies is the way to go.

**Spell Conversions**

**Edit!**

I didn't notice "CtL" in the original post. This can be done in changeling with Contracts and Pledges as well. For Knock, as @Frew mentions in the comments, this can be done by entering a pledge with a lock, though I think you'd have to finagle it to work with every lock (I can't recall if you can enter a pledge with all locks since that would be more the purview of a contract, but you could enter a pledge with a specific lock on the fly to duplicate the spell).

For Speak with Dead, there's a Darkling contract [Shade and Spirit](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Shade_and_Spirit) which does the same thing, though it has some restrictions.

Fireball is probably [Elements 4](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Elements)...

Overall you can paruse the Contracts on the [White Wolf Wikia](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Contract), there are several which duplicate spell effects.

The problem is here that Changelings aren't much adept at spell crafting so much as they have several spell-like abilities gained with their contracts with various things, which makes it harder to get access to spells than it would be in a D&D setting.

Comment: The OP is running *Changeling*; I think it's a little much to ask him to familiarize himself with an entirely different core book -- especially one as intricate as *Awakening*. Think it could be done with Contracts instead?

Comment: @Jadasc, I looked at various contracts and really extremely few of them can do things as generic as these spells.  Of course none of the characters are Mages, and adding one at this point would completely change the flavor of the game.  My thought is that the characters may be able to just use pledges (with inanimate objects) to achieve similar results.

Comment: @Frew That's a fine idea. The "Knock" spell as a deal with Locks, and so on.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed the CtL in the OP! Those would work great as contracts, I'll spin up a few examples.

Comment: I've added some links to various contracts that already fit the bill, and some commentary on using pledges for "Knock", which is an excellent idea.

Comment: @Cthos Good going! Upvoted.

Answer (score 6):

There are a ton of nwod books which provide antagonists of various crunches and powers. I'd suggest not doing a point for point conversion, but rather do an instance for instance conversion. Zombies into Zombies, rather then stats to stats.

Comment: That works for monsters, but what about spells?  I have *no clue* how  to convert Knock, Speak with the Dead, etc